# How to insert row to n number of sections dynamically in UITableview

Tags: iphone, ipad

How to update number of rows in

`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    }`

When it will expand increase number of rows.

`- (void) rotateButtonToExpanded:(UIButton*)aButton section:(int)aSection{

```
// Rotate the button with animation.
[UIView beginAnimations:ROTATE_TO_EXPAND context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION];
aButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*2.5);
[UIView commitAnimations];

// Save the state (expanded or collapsed) of button with index path as key.
BOOL isExpanded=![[mStateOfNodes objectAtIndex:aSection] isExpanded];
[[mStateOfNodes objectAtIndex:aSection] setIsExpanded:isExpanded];

NSArray*theDataOfChildCells=[[self.mNodes objectAtIndex:aSection] valueForKey:CHILD_NODES];


for (int i=0; i<theDataOfChildCells.count; i++) {
    mNumberOfCells++;

    [self beginUpdates];
    NSIndexPath*theIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:aSection];
    [self insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
    [self endUpdates];

}

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

used reload data methods,

```
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following code that use for add row in `UITable` with specific row and section

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNO inSection:SectionNO];
        [self.tblView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        rowNO=rowNO+1;
     [self.tblView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
        [self.tblView reloadData];
```

Comment: but for n number of sections how can I keep track of number of rows?

Comment: add SectionNO = SectionNO + 1 ;...and also you should mention that how many row u want to insert in n number of section??